# PaperDb arraylist is not reading

Tags: java, android, paperdb

```
ArrayList<Orders> ordersArrayList;

ordersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

ordersArrayList = Paper.book().read("ordersArrayList");
```

This is how I writing object

```
 ordersArrayList.add(orders);

 Paper.book().write("ordersArrayList", ordersArrayList);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or simply getting empty results? Also, can you confirm directly in the Db that it is writing properly?

Comment: getting This Error                                                                                         Couldn't read/deserialize file /data/user/0/com.moodie.android/files/io.paperdb/com.moodie.android.data.USER.pt for table orderayyarlist

Answer (score 0):

First, until you don't store any data in a key, in your case `ordersArrayList` you should not use the `read` function, it will generate errors. So to do this in a proper way follow here:

1st method :

```
ArrayList<Orders> ordersArrayList;

ordersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

dummyArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

ordersArrayList = Paper.book().read("ordersArrayList",dummyArrayList);

ordersArrayList.add(orders);

 Paper.book().write("ordersArrayList", ordersArrayList);
```

As the `read` function's 2nd parameter is the default value of the `key` so if it is null it will replace it with the default value.

2nd method:

```
ArrayList<Orders> ordersArrayList;

ordersArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

dummyArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

if(Paper.book().read("ordersArrayList")!=null){
ordersArrayList = Paper.book().read("ordersArrayList");
}
ordersArrayList.add(orders);

 Paper.book().write("ordersArrayList", ordersArrayList);
```